# 500 Error when saving settings in GitLab (docker)

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab-ce

I'm running a GitLab container in docker. When I'm trying to save settings in Admin Area (in specific, Settings - General), it hangs for 60 sec and redirect me to 500 page.

The server run in an air-gapped intranet, without Internet connection.

Here's the `docker-compose.yml` file I'm using:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:16.6.2-ce.0'
    ports:
      - '20080:80'
      - '20443:443'
      - '20022:22'
    shm_size: '1gb'
```

The possible related log is shown below:

```json
{
  "method": "PATCH",
  "path": "/admin/application_settings/general",
  "format": "html",
  "controller": "Admin::ApplicationSettingsController",
  "action": "general",
  "status": 500,
  "time": "2023-12-18T07:59:15.696Z",
  "params": [
    {
      "key": "_method",
      "value": "patch"
    },
    {
      "key": "authenticity_token",
      "value": "[FILTERED]"
    },
    {
      "key": "application_setting",
      "value": {
        "import_sources": [
          "",
          "gitlab_project"
        ],
        "project_export_enabled": "1",
        "bulk_import_enabled": "0",
        "max_export_size": "0",
        "max_import_size": "0",
        "max_import_remote_file_size": "10240",
        "bulk_import_max_download_file_size": "5120",
        "max_decompressed_archive_size": "25600",
        "decompress_archive_file_timeout": "210"
      }
    }
  ],
  "correlation_id": "01HHXYXH7MKN0EKV8DSJG3KCP0",
  "meta.caller_id": "Admin::ApplicationSettingsController#general",
  "meta.remote_ip": "12.70.170.3",
  "meta.feature_category": "not_owned",
  "meta.user": "root",
  "meta.user_id": 1,
  "meta.client_id": "user/1",
  "remote_ip": "12.70.170.3",
  "user_id": 1,
  "username": "root",
  "ua": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Safari/605.1.15",
  "queue_duration_s": 0.061149,
  "request_urgency": "default",
  "target_duration_s": 1,
  "redis_calls": 12,
  "redis_allowed_cross_slot_calls": 1,
  "redis_duration_s": 0.006305,
  "redis_read_bytes": 1492,
  "redis_write_bytes": 1127,
  "redis_feature_flag_calls": 7,
  "redis_feature_flag_duration_s": 0.003357,
  "redis_feature_flag_read_bytes": 1312,
  "redis_feature_flag_write_bytes": 436,
  "redis_sessions_calls": 3,
  "redis_sessions_allowed_cross_slot_calls": 1,
  "redis_sessions_duration_s": 0.002376,
  "redis_sessions_read_bytes": 180,
  "redis_sessions_write_bytes": 587,
  "redis_shared_state_calls": 2,
  "redis_shared_state_duration_s": 0.000572,
  "redis_shared_state_write_bytes": 104,
  "db_count": 4,
  "db_write_count": 0,
  "db_cached_count": 1,
  "db_replica_count": 0,
  "db_primary_count": 4,
  "db_main_count": 4,
  "db_ci_count": 0,
  "db_main_replica_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_count": 0,
  "db_replica_cached_count": 0,
  "db_primary_cached_count": 1,
  "db_main_cached_count": 1,
  "db_ci_cached_count": 0,
  "db_main_replica_cached_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_cached_count": 0,
  "db_replica_wal_count": 0,
  "db_primary_wal_count": 0,
  "db_main_wal_count": 0,
  "db_ci_wal_count": 0,
  "db_main_replica_wal_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_wal_count": 0,
  "db_replica_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_primary_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_main_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_ci_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_main_replica_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_replica_duration_s": 0.0,
  "db_primary_duration_s": 0.013,
  "db_main_duration_s": 0.013,
  "db_ci_duration_s": 0.0,
  "db_main_replica_duration_s": 0.0,
  "db_ci_replica_duration_s": 0.0,
  "cpu_s": 0.389744,
  "mem_objects": 183156,
  "mem_bytes": 19300163,
  "mem_mallocs": 84754,
  "mem_total_bytes": 26626403,
  "pid": 1108,
  "worker_id": "puma_2",
  "rate_limiting_gates": [],
  "exception.class": "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid",
  "exception.message": "PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() FATAL:  terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout\nserver closed the connection unexpectedly\n\tThis probably means the server terminated abnormally\n\tbefore or while processing the request.\n",
  "exception.backtrace": [
    "lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:127:in `public_send'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:127:in `block in write_using_load_balancer'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:137:in `block in read_write'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:224:in `retry_with_backoff'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/load_balancer.rb:126:in `read_write'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:126:in `write_using_load_balancer'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/connection_proxy.rb:78:in `transaction'",
    "app/services/application_settings/update_service.rb:51:in `update_settings'",
    "app/services/application_settings/update_service.rb:12:in `execute'",
    "app/controllers/admin/application_settings_controller.rb:210:in `perform_update'",
    "app/controllers/admin/application_settings_controller.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ApplicationSettingsController>'",
    "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:498:in `set_current_admin'",
    "lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in `with_session'",
    "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:489:in `set_session_storage'",
    "lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:114:in `with_locale'",
    "lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:120:in `with_user_locale'",
    "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:480:in `set_locale'",
    "app/controllers/application_controller.rb:473:in `set_current_context'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/elasticsearch_rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/memory_report.rb:13:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/speedscope.rb:13:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/rack_middleware.rb:23:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:33:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:21:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `block in call'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/web_transaction.rb:46:in `run'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/query_analyzer.rb:11:in `block in call'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/query_analyzer.rb:37:in `within'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/query_analyzer.rb:11:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:173:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:50:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/path_traversal_check.rb:48:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_malformed_strings.rb:21:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:15:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/webhook_recursion_detection.rb:15:in `call'",
    "config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:11:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/compressed_json.rb:44:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/rack_multipart_tempfile_factory.rb:19:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/sidekiq_web_static.rb:20:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:79:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:13:in `call'"
  ],
  "exception.cause_class": "PG::ConnectionBad",
  "exception.sql": "/*application:web,correlation_id:01HHXYXH7MKN0EKV8DSJG3KCP0,endpoint_id:Admin::ApplicationSettingsController#general,db_config_name:main*/ ROLLBACK",
  "db_duration_s": 0.43426,
  "view_duration_s": 0.0,
  "duration_s": 60.6218
}



{
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "time": "2023-12-15T07:04:14.029Z",
  "correlation_id": "01HHP4KVN86B6FY4BQP52C3HD1",
  "meta.caller_id": "ExternalServiceReactiveCachingWorker",
  "meta.remote_ip": "12.70.170.3",
  "meta.feature_category": "groups_and_projects",
  "meta.user": "root",
  "meta.user_id": 1,
  "meta.client_id": "user/1",
  "meta.related_class": "VersionCheck",
  "meta.root_caller_id": "RootController#index",
  "exception.class": "Gitlab::HTTP_V2::BlockedUrlError",
  "exception.message": "URL is blocked: Host cannot be resolved or invalid",
  "exception.backtrace": [
    "lib/gitlab/http_connection_adapter.rb:60:in `rescue in validate_url_with_proxy!'",
    "lib/gitlab/http_connection_adapter.rb:52:in `validate_url_with_proxy!'",
    "lib/gitlab/http_connection_adapter.rb:29:in `connection'",
    "lib/gitlab/legacy_http.rb:37:in `perform_request'",
    "lib/gitlab/http.rb:48:in `public_send'",
    "lib/gitlab/http.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in singleton class'",
    "lib/gitlab/http.rb:54:in `try_get'",
    "lib/version_check.rb:71:in `calculate_reactive_cache'",
    "app/models/concerns/reactive_caching.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in exclusively_update_reactive_cache!'",
    "app/models/concerns/reactive_caching.rb:153:in `enqueuing_update'",
    "app/models/concerns/reactive_caching.rb:93:in `block in exclusively_update_reactive_cache!'",
    "app/models/concerns/reactive_caching.rb:143:in `locking_reactive_cache'",
    "app/models/concerns/reactive_caching.rb:89:in `exclusively_update_reactive_cache!'",
    "app/workers/concerns/reactive_cacheable_worker.rb:35:in `perform'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/skip_jobs.rb:49:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/sidekiq_server_middleware.rb:29:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/duplicate_jobs/strategies/until_executing.rb:16:in `perform'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/duplicate_jobs/duplicate_job.rb:44:in `perform'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/duplicate_jobs/server.rb:8:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/pause_control/strategies/base.rb:31:in `perform'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/pause_control/strategy_handler.rb:22:in `perform'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/pause_control/server.rb:8:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/worker_context.rb:9:in `wrap_in_optional_context'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/worker_context/server.rb:19:in `block in call'",
    "lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:124:in `block in use'",
    "lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:124:in `use'",
    "lib/gitlab/application_context.rb:62:in `with_context'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/worker_context/server.rb:17:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_status/server_middleware.rb:7:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_versioning/middleware.rb:9:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/query_analyzer.rb:7:in `block in call'",
    "lib/gitlab/database/query_analyzer.rb:37:in `within'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/query_analyzer.rb:7:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/admin_mode/server.rb:14:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/instrumentation_logger.rb:9:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/batch_loader.rb:7:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/extra_done_log_metadata.rb:7:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/request_store_middleware.rb:8:in `block in call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/request_store_middleware.rb:7:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/server_metrics.rb:94:in `block in call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/server_metrics.rb:122:in `block in instrument'",
    "lib/gitlab/metrics/background_transaction.rb:33:in `run'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/server_metrics.rb:122:in `instrument'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/server_metrics.rb:93:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/monitor.rb:10:in `block in call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_daemon/monitor.rb:46:in `within_job'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/monitor.rb:9:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_middleware/size_limiter/server.rb:13:in `call'",
    "lib/gitlab/sidekiq_logging/structured_logger.rb:21:in `call'"
  ],
  "exception.cause_class": "Gitlab::HTTP_V2::UrlBlocker::BlockedUrlError",
  "user.username": "root",
  "tags.program": "sidekiq",
  "tags.locale": "en",
  "tags.feature_category": "groups_and_projects",
  "tags.correlation_id": "01HHP4KVN86B6FY4BQP52C3HD1",
  "extra.sidekiq": {
    "retry": 3,
    "queue": "default",
    "version": 0,
    "args": [
      "VersionCheck",
      "[FILTERED]"
    ],
    "class": "ExternalServiceReactiveCachingWorker",
    "jid": "e6244186fac178cc1209a3c7",
    "created_at": 1702623833.9807603,
    "correlation_id": "01HHP4KVN86B6FY4BQP52C3HD1",
    "meta.caller_id": "RootController#index",
    "meta.remote_ip": "12.70.170.3",
    "meta.feature_category": "groups_and_projects",
    "meta.user": "root",
    "meta.user_id": 1,
    "meta.client_id": "user/1",
    "meta.related_class": "VersionCheck",
    "meta.root_caller_id": "RootController#index",
    "worker_data_consistency": "always",
    "idempotency_key": "resque:gitlab:duplicate:default:b610d442fdc82b690dca61a846f215244f166bae201a51f5e520beb3a0cfe345",
    "size_limiter": "validated",
    "enqueued_at": 1702623833.9836192
  }
    }
```

Related Postgre log `/var/log/gitlab/postgresql/current`:

```
FATAL:  terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout
```

Possibly related to an open issue [#422312](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/422312) Gitlab 16.x on Ky10.x86_64 cannt save changes in settings. (Error 500.)

---

I ran the same configuration on a test server with Internet connection and latest `image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest` and it works fine.

Also tried older `image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:16.5.0-ce.0'` whereas the issue remains.